# How to skip first 3 rows of a text file?

Tags: java

When I read the text file using Java, how can I skip first three rows of the text file?

Current program,

```
public class Reader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream("sample.txt")));
            Map<String, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
            Map<String, Integer> result2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
            while (reader.ready()) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                //split a line with spaces
                String[] values = line.split("\s+");
                //set a key date\tanimal
                String key = values[0] + "\t" + values[1];
                int sum = 0;
                int count = 0;
                //get a last counter and sum
                if (result.containsKey(key)) {
                    sum = result.get(key);
                    count = result2.get(key);
                } else{

                }
                //increment sum a count and save in the map with key
                result.put(key, sum + Integer.parseInt(values[2]));
                result2.put(key, count + 1);
            }

            //interate and print new output
            for (String key : result.keySet()) {
                Integer sum = result.get(key);
                Integer count = result2.get(key);
                System.out.println(key + " " + sum + "\t" + count);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please layout your code so it can be read and use the magic word "please" before "show me".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why can't you just do this?

```
//Skip 3 lines.
for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
    reader.readLine();
}
```

You can simplify the code and make it more readable by introducing these two classes. Then you can only maintain 1 Map,

```
Map<Animal, Summary> result = new HashMap<Animal, Summary>();

class Animal
{
    String date;

    String name;

    public Animal(final String date, final String n)
    {
        this.date = date;
        this.name = n;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((date == null) ? 0 : date.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Animal))
        {
            return false;
        }
        Animal other = (Animal) obj;
        if (date == null)
        {
            if (other.date != null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (!date.equals(other.date))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (name == null)
        {
            if (other.name != null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

final static class Summary
{
    private int total;

    private int count;

    void setTotal(int value)
    {
        total = value;
    }

    void setCount(int i)
    {
        count = i;
    }

    void increaseCount()
    {
        count++;
    }

    void addToTotal(int valueToAdd)
    {
        total += valueToAdd;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are after conciseness and readability, you should extract the loop which skips lines in a method with a signature like goToLine(BufferedReader br, int lineNumber) or even create your own decorator LineSkippingReader which skips a certain amount of lines.

Comment: agree but I am not providing him the complete solution only few suggestions with code examples.

Answer (score 4):

An easy example I think:

```
public String[] readTextFile(String fileName, int skipLines) throws IOException
{
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fStream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    String readLine;        
    int curLineNr = 1;

    while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        if (curLineNr++ <= skipLines) {
            continue;
        }

        lines.add(readLine);
    }

    in.close();

    return lines.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("")));
  b.readLine();
  b.readLine();
  b.readLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple but effective solution add 3 calls before the loop

```
reader.readLine(); // or use a loop
reader.readLine();
reader.readLine();
while(reader.ready()){ //blah blah blah
```

Comment: Dear Downvoter, if you could please justify your DV, i'd be grateful. - `st0le`

Answer (score 1):

There is no information stored for text files in the Windows and Unix filesystems that allow easy navigation to a given line.  You essentially must read all the file from the beginning to be certain you are at the right location.  Other operating systems allow for storing text files in a form that allow this, but at other costs.

In this particular case, it is quite simple though.  Just read the three lines you want to skip by wrapping with a BufferedReader and invoking readLine(), and start processing from there.

You might also find LIneNumberReader interesting - http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html